# "Can't resolve 'encoding'" warning in NextJS caused by try/require from `node_modules`

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, apollo-server, node-fetch

In a NextJS `13.4.19` app in typescript, using `@apollo/server@4.9.3` causes a warning at the build step, coming from ApolloServer/node-fetch. This seems caused by a `try / require` in `node-fetch`:

- `./node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js`:

```js
let convert;
try {
  convert = require('encoding').convert;
} catch (e) {}
```

- Warning:

```
- warn Compiled with warnings

./node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'encoding' in 'C:<...>\apollo-server-encoding-warn\node_modules\node-fetch\lib'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js
./node_modules/@apollo/server/dist/esm/plugin/schemaReporting/schemaReporter.js
./node_modules/@apollo/server/dist/esm/plugin/schemaReporting/index.js
./node_modules/@apollo/server/dist/esm/ApolloServer.js
./node_modules/@apollo/server/dist/esm/index.js
./app/api/graphql/route.ts
```

- `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Manually installing the `encoding` package acts as a workaround to remove this warning, but it's not a very satisfying solution as I wouldn't want to install every future package which presence is checked using this pattern.

This warning happens both when building and running in dev mode, is there a way I can tell NextJs/typescript to not report these warnings when they're coming from `node_modules` ? Or is it symptomatic of something else that I missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding that this warning was in fact coming from Webpack, and while browsing the options I found that I could target-suppress it by updating the `next.config.js` file as follow:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.ignoreWarnings = [
      // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#ignorewarnings
      {
        module: /node-fetch/,
        message: /.*Can't resolve 'encoding'.*/,
      },
    ];

    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced this warn while running Apollo server with NextJS 13

To fix this issue, you can try the following:

1. **Install the `encoding` module.**

```bash
npm install encoding
```

or

```bash
yarn add encoding
```

2. **Restart your development server.** This will ensure that the changes you made to your `node_modules` directory are picked up.

Comment: This solution works and I came across it while searching, but the problem I have with it is that it's not a "fix" per se, but rather a workaround, as clearly the `encoding` module isn't required for the application to work. I wanted a generic solution that would ignore Webpack's false positive warnings raised by the `try require / catch` pattern.